# Insert two values into MariaDB table using a textarea in HTML - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to add some text from a TEXTAREA in HTML to my table in mariaDB using PHP in Linux.
Basically the form has two "boxes". One to identify the user and the second one to add a text.
If the user have already added a text, will not be possible to add more text.
I am struggling to add the name and the text from TEXTAREA (from HTML) using a query in PHP.
Any ideas??

This is my table in MariaDB:

```
create table TableMarch(
         id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
         name varchar(255) UNIQUE,
         messagetext TEXT,
         date DATE NOT NULL,
         PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );
```

This is my form in html:

```
---SOMETHING---
.
.
.
<body>
<form action="form_submit.php" class="alt" method="POST">
        <div>  <img class="marginauto" src="image.JPG" alt="centered image" /> </div>
        <h2> <center>APP</center></h2>
        <label for="name">ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="ID"/>
        <textarea name="message" for="message" placeholder="Please, type your message" maxlength="300"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my code in PHP:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$db_name = "dev_to";
$username = "XXX";
$password = "XXX";
$connection = null;
try{
$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db_name, $username, $password);
$connection->exec("set names utf8");
}catch(PDOException $exception){
echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
}
function saveData($name){
global $connection;
$query = "INSERT INTO TableMarch(name, messagetext) VALUES( :name , :messagetext )";
$callToDb = $connection->prepare( $query );
$name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($name));
$messagetext = $_POST['messagetext'];
//$callToDb->bindParam(":name", $name);
$callToDb->bindParam(":name", $name, ":messagetext", $messagetext );
if (!$callToDb->execute()) {

    $_SESSION['message']='This is your message';
    $affected_rows = $callToDb->rowCount();
    if ($affected_rows == 0) {
    
      $query2 = "SELECT date FROM test WHERE name = ?";
      $result2 = $connection->prepare($query2);
      $result2->execute([$name]);
      $datee = $result2->fetch();
      foreach ($datee as $value);
      printf('<h1> User ' . $name . ' has already sent a comment: ' . $value . '</h1>' );
      echo '<p><a href="http://xx.xx.xx.xx/app.html" title="Return to previous page">&laquo; return to app</a></p>';
   }
} else {
       printf('<h1> Thanks for sending your comment. </h1>'); 
       echo '<p><a href="http://xx.xx.xx.xx/aplicativo.html" title="Return to previous page">&laquo; return to app</a></p>';
}


}


if( isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
//then you can use them in a PHP function. 
$result = saveData($name);
//echo $result;


}

else{
echo '<h3 style="text-align:center;">ERROR WITH LOGIN</h3>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Please do not add inappropriate tags that make your question look off topic spammy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing comma between values try

```sql
INSERT INTO TableMarch(name, messagetext) VALUES( :name , :messagetext)
```

Also turn on PDO exceptions:

```php
$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db_name, $username, $password);
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

You'll see an error in your case (or maybe some other)

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'date' doesn't have a default value in ...

If you'll allow `date` field to be null or always will insert valid date record will be inserted.

Just tested.

Also! Make sure that `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['textmessage']` are sent.

As I can see, in form you have `name="message"` but trying to fetch `textmessage`. Pls fix all these bugs first. Use debugger and browser's inspector to make sure all required data arrives to the script.

Comment: This part looks fine for you?    messagetext = $HTTP_POST_VARS['messagetext'];

Comment: I already added the ","  and $_POST but it is not working. The name and text is not added in the table.

Comment: `PDOStatement::bindParam ( mixed $parameter , mixed &$variable , int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR , int $length = ? , mixed $driver_options = ? )` you are trying (key, value, key value)

Comment: How should I re-do the code to make it works then? Thanks

Comment: bind each param separately.

Comment: I think this is not correct right??    $callToDb->bindParam(":name", $name,);
$callToDb->bindParam(":messagetext", $messagetext ); May you please add this in a comment to see how i should do this?

Comment: Sorry, the code seems ok but i get a NULL value when querying the databse in messagetext. And no date is added as well. The text it is not added. Only the name is added

Comment: Ok now the text it is added!! But the date it is not added. Amways is 0000-00-00. Theoretically it was added automatically after each entry.

Comment: Because you don't add it in your INSERT query and you don't set default value of field for NOW

Comment: Is it not possible to add date automatically from mysql?

Comment: It is, I just wrote before

Comment: I think now it is working. Thanks i will post again my code completed just to help others. Thanks.

Comment: First try to cleanup your code, analyze and debug it. Next if you won't find solution write new question with fresh code samples